# What is the host of heaven in 2 Kgs. 17:16; 21:3 & 2 Chr. 33:3

Tags: hebrew-bible, angels, idolatry

In 2 Kings and 2 Chronicles, it speaks of the Israelites and their leaders worshipping "all the host of heaven". The term host of heaven can refer to angels and also the stars/planets.

**Angels**

Joshua 5:13-15; 1 Kings 22:20-21; Luke 2:13; (probably) Nehemiah 9:6

**Stars/Planets**

Deuteronomy 17:3; Jeremiah 8:2

Which of these two meanings is the best interpretation in regard to the passages in 2 Kings and 2 Chronicles? Were the Israelites worshipping the stars and planets, or were they worshipping all the spiritual beings?

Comment: In Greek στρατεύματι τοῦ οὐρανοῦ  strategy(of heaven) is a group of beings, a force of 4096 men 2^13. Η βασιλεια Queen means a (female) leader of army. So check this too https://biblehub.com/topical/q/queen_of_heaven.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is quite correct in saying that "the host of haven: can refer to either:

- heavenly beings (including angels), or
- astronomical bodies such as stars, sun, moon, and planets, etc.

The distinction between the two is questioned in three texts.  Before addressing these texts we should observe that the Bible records no instance angel worship in the Bible (such began during the medieval period) - all worship of "the heavenly host" is directed to the sun, moon and stars.  However, we have numerous instances of the heavenly beings (= "host") worshiping God.

Now, let us examine the texts.

> **2 Kings 17:16** - They abandoned all the commandments of the LORD their
> God and made for themselves two cast idols of calves and an Asherah
> pole. They bowed down to all **the host of heaven** and served Baal.

This is a reference to the heavenly bodies such as the sun, moon and stars.

> **2 Kings 21:3** - For he rebuilt the high places that his father Hezekiah had destroyed, and he raised up altars for Baal. He made an
> Asherah pole, as King Ahab of Israel had done, and he worshiped and
> served all **the host of heaven**. (same as 2 Chron 33:3)

Again, This is a reference to the heavenly bodies such as the sun, moon and stars.

This is in direct opposition to the direction given in the Torah against such practices:

- Deut 4:19 - When you look to the heavens and see **the sun and moon and stars—all the host of heaven**—do not be enticed to bow down and worship what the LORD your God has apportioned to all the nations under heaven.
- Deut 17:3 - and going to worship other gods, bowing down to them or to **the sun or moon or any of the host of heaven**—which I have forbidden

The same practice is condemned elsewhere:

- Jer 8:2 - They will be exposed to **the sun and moon, and to all the host of heaven** which they have loved, served, followed, consulted, and worshiped. Their bones will not be gathered up or buried, but will become like dung lying on the ground.
- 2 Kings 23:5 - Josiah also did away with the idolatrous priests ordained by the kings of Judah to burn incense on the high places of the cities of Judah and in the places all around Jerusalem—those who had burned incense to Baal, to **the sun and moon, to the constellations, and to all the host of heaven**.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @Dottard's answer I would add that in Mesopotamian and Canaanite religion - as well as later Greek and Roman mythology - the sun and the planets were associated with specific deities. In the Babylonian case, the most important of these was Marduk (also called Bel). From the [New World Encyclopedia](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Mesopotamian_Religion):

> Astral theology served as the theoretical substratum of the Babylonian
> religion, and was equally pronounced in the religious system of
> Assyria. The essential feature of this astral theology is the
> assumption of a close link between the movements going on in the
> heavens and occurrences on earth. This led to identifying the gods and
> goddesses with heavenly bodies and to assigning the seats of all the
> deities in the heavens. Marduk, the supreme deity, was portrayed as
> the one who set the celestial bodies in their places and ruled over
> them all.
>
> The personification of the two great luminaries—the sun and the moon
> (Shamash and Sin)—was the first step in the unfolding of this system.
> This process led to identifying the planet Venus with Ishtar, Jupiter
> with Marduk, Mars with Nergal, Mercury with Nabu, and Saturn with
> Ninurta.

Thus, in worshiping the "host of heaven" people were not simply venerating the heavenly bodies but also honoring the deities that they represented. The 20th century Assyriologist [Achibald Sayce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archibald_Sayce) and others taught that the angels of monotheistic tradition grew out of the the tradition of a supreme deity who ruled over lesser gods associated with the heavenly host. Today, some in the Christian world associate [specific archangels](https://apollotarot.com/blogs/insights/what-is-the-sigil-of-the-7-archangels) with corresponding heavenly bodies - Michael with the Sun; Gabriel with the Moon; Raphael with Mercury, etc.  However, there is no known evidence that this was the case in the ancient world.

The Jewish religion, on the other hand, stressed that there is only one God, and the heavenly bodies were his creations. In so doing, it also exalted the place of human beings in the cosmological order:

Psalm 8

> When I see your heavens, the work of your fingers,
> the moon and stars that you set in place— 5 What is man that you are mindful of him,
> and a son of man that you care for him? 6 Yet you have made him little less than a god,
> crowned him with glory and honor. 7 You have given him rule over the works of your hands,
> put all things at his feet...10 O Lord, our Lord,
> how awesome is your name through all the earth!